# opera printing only few pages

Tags: printing, opera

I want to print many pages from a web page, but opera prints only a few of them.

The problem seems to be with the css style of blocks.

If some blocks have `position:absolute` and others have `float`, not all pages print. 
If I drop this property or set `* {min-height:100px;}`, all pages print. It look like Opera calculates the height of printed document wrong.

Opera 11.51 or Opera 12 alpha on windows & linux. On MacOS everything works fine.

Comment: Can you post a link to the page so we can test it out and see if it is an Opera bug or not?

Answer (score 0):

It could well be an Opera bug, but without the page involved there is no way for us to find out.

However if setting a minimum height works around the issue you could just set it for printing only like this:

```
@media print {
  * {min-height:100px;}
}
```

Comment: you will get auto-bounty +25 rep, but this is simply ridiculous. You quoted original post and call it an answer ? have you no shame ?

Comment: I didn't just quote, I added the suggestion to use this rule just when printing. I'm well aware it's just a workaround, as I mention in the answer, but given the lack of an example to test against it's the best I can do. Feel free to come up with something better though. (That and nevermind the fact this is the first time I read about auto-bounty, had to look it up...)